# Is there a way to edit two instances of the same sub-string in a list differently?

Tags: python

I have a large list that contains two identical lines. For the first occurrence of this string, I want to do certain edits, and for the second I want to do different edits.

I have tried using a state function as well as some regex stuff without working. I am looking to edit a list that could take the form:

```
lots of words
lots of words

Contingency 17 - Reno - Vegas
more words

Contingency 17 - Reno - Vegas
still more
```

I know this is not pythonic, but I am looking for some code that would essentially do:

```
for line in file.readlines()
    if first.("Contingency 17") in line:
        #do stuff (I know how to do this section)
    elif next.("Contingency") in line:
        #do other stuff (I know this as well)
    else:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Hopefully this would edit the first and next instances of a string differently in a large text file. I need help selecting the two lines to edit in different fashions. An example output of this would be:

```
lots of words
lots of words

Contingency 20 - Reno - Carson City
more words

Contingency 25 - Carson City - Vegas
still more
```

Comment: Could you make the problem more specific posting a sample input that is an actual list, and an expected output?

Comment: I've added some more info. Thanks for the comment. Of note, I know how to edit the lines, but am having trouble making the distinct edits. Right now, both lines are changed to `Contingency 20 - Reno - Carson City`

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. You're saying you have a list of strings, but anywhere I see a list, or strings. Then suddenly in the code you read from a file. Try to define more accurately the inputs and outputs of your problem. what does `first` and `next` supposed to represent in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def fun_to_apply_to_first_line(line):
    return line.upper()

def fun_to_apply_to_second_line(line):
    return 2*line

list_of_lines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd']

pattern = 'b'

funlist = [fun_to_apply_to_first_line, fun_to_apply_to_second_line]
new_list = []
for line in list_of_lines:
    value = line
    if line == pattern:
        fun = funlist.pop(0)
        value = fun(line)
    new_list.append(value)

print(list(zip(list_of_lines, new_list)))

>>> [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'c'), ('b', 'bb'), ('d', 'd')]
```

The biggest issue here is you must know how many occurrences of your pattern there are. If you don't care about that, and all you want to do is apply a function to the first occurrence and a different function to all subsequent occurrences, use a state flag:

```
def fun_to_apply_first(line):
    return line.upper()

def fun_to_apply_rest(line):
    return 2*line

list_of_lines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'b']

pattern = 'b'
is_first = True
new_list = []
for line in list_of_lines:
    value = line
    if line == pattern:
        value = fun_to_apply_first(line) if is_first else fun_to_apply_rest(line)
    new_list.append(value)

print(list(zip(list_of_lines, new_list)))

>>> [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'c'), ('b', 'B'), ('d', 'd'), ('b', 'B'), ('b', 'B')]
```

Obviously without the print() statement at the end. This is very brittle and will be cumbersome with lots of patterns, so you might consider a lookup dict of functions:

```
lookup_fun_dict = {'b': [first_fun, second_fun], 'c': [first_fun, third_fun]}
```

I would also probably use lambdas instead of functions if the operations are simple.

This is quite brittle, and I'm sure others will think of an elegant solution. If there are very many occurrences of `pattern` and the operations you apply to it are expensive, you might just use a static value to replace `pattern` with, or at least memoize it.

Comment: The first option you listed seems to be working well. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. As I said, this is brittle. I would not use this in production code - there are lots of gotchas here. If you exhaust your list of functions and encounter another instance of `pattern`, this will break. It's also a bear to maintain. However if this is for a small project or one-off thing I think it'll be fine.

Comment: There should only be 2 of the pattern max. And yes, it is my first major coding project so I know I will have to refine it a bit once I get everything working. One more bug to figure out! Thank you for your input.